# Redirect в OpenCart

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, redirect, редирект

Сейчас в OpenCart 2.3 такой .htaccess

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Появилась необходимость переходить по адресу `/deeper-start?roistat=direct6_{source_type}_{banner_id}_{keyword}&roistat_referrer={source}&roistat_pos={position_type}_{position}`
Но последний редирект режет все что после "?" Отключая его падают все страницы. Можно ли это как-то обойти?

p.s. Если добавить страницу в исключения, то при переходе на нее - not found

Comment: de_frag когда я добавляю страницу в исключения ее url выбивает not found

Comment: Да, поторопился. Вам же надо этот адрес через тот же самый роутинг прогнать.

Comment: Проблема не в редиректе, а в роутере ЧПУ. Если стоит SEO PRO, то решение [по ссылке](https://opencartforum.com/topic/24946-resheno-seo-pro-rezhet-ssylku/?tab=comments#comment-225029).